# ERROR: Could not build wheels for PyNaCl which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly

Tags: python, pycharm, pep, pynacl, pep517

I'm using the latest Version of `Pycharm`:

When I Enter this command:

```bash
pip install -U discord.py[voice]
```

This Error Message shows:

`ERROR: Could not build wheels for PyNaCl which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly`

What should I do?

Comment: Has the same message when trying to compile PEP 517 under alpine Linux - my issue was that I was missing 'make' - after installing it (with `apk add make`) it allowed me to compile PEP successfully.

Comment: @kyrisu: installing `make` fixed the problem here on a Ubuntu 20.04 LTS AWS EC2 instance, too - you might want to turn your comment into an answer :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`PEP 517` was known to have some problems with `virtualenvs` so that could be a likely cause.

Try to perform these commands and see if that works

```
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install --no-use-pep517 discord.py[voice]
```

If not try to downgrade your pip version

```
pip install pip==18.1
```

and then try the package install command again.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks, @kyrisu, your solution actually worked installing make did the trick for certain cloud packages it throws an error if there is no `cmake` installed too. Adding the command which I used on my alpine image.

```
RUN apk add --no-cache make cmake
```

This adds both make and `cmake` and post that the dependencies are installed without any issues.

Answer (score 1):

Try to install binutils first before installing `PyNaCl` on *Termux*.

```bash
pkg install binutils
```

Comment: This resolved my issue on Termux.

Answer (score 0):

```
[root@username ~]# pip3 install -U discord.py[voice]
```

above worked for me ^^ on RHEL 8.